# DataMapper associates that depend on two columns

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have a table of products with attributes like SKU, Name, etc.

It seems like I need to have separate tables for each category of product due to the large variety of features depending on the category.

Say I have a table/class for boots, tools and hats

I'd like (unless there's a better way) to join/associate my products table to the other tables where appropriate (depending on category)?

```
Products Table  

id | Name   | SKU | Category(Table) | CategoryTableForeignKey
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | boot1  | 123 | Boots           | 2
2  | knife1 | 345 | Tools           | 42
```

-

```
Boots Table

id | product_id   | Size | Width | Color | Sex
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 1            | 9.5  | Wide  | Olive | Male
```

-

```
Tools Table

id | product_id   | length | Fixed | Coating | Etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
42 | 2            | 4.5    | False | ...     | ...
```

I'm not sure how to do this with DataMapper classes.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to:

```
my_boot = Boots.get(1)

my_boot.product.sku
```

**Edit:** dkubb pointed out a flaw in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `has()` what you're saying is that the foreign key is in the *other* model. If you want the foreign key to be in the table associated with the current model you want to use `belongs_to`.

Comment: Ok, good point. But how might I join the Boots table to only some of the records in the products table? It seems like I'd have to have a lot of <table>_id columns in the products table.

Comment: I believe I figured it out, thanks to your help. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product
  include DataMapper::Resource
  #descripe product properties ...

  has n,  :boots
end

Class Boot
  include DataMapper::Resource
  #describe boot properties ...

  belongs_to :product
end
```

About DataMapper Associations: http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html